# Как передать загруженный файл внутри класса, из одного метода в другой?

Tags: laravel

подскажите как передать загруженный файл из одного метода в другую в переделах класса, один метод вызывается из другого?

```
class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
    }

    public function store()
    {
        // получить доступ к загруженному файлу из метода upload
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря как вызывать метод, но... к примеру так. Но лучше всего для таких вещей использовать сервисы или операции. Контроллер не должен обрабатывать логику.

```php
class FileController extends Controller
{
    public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('file');
        $this->store($file);
    }

    protected function store($file)
    {
        $result = $file; // файл
    }
}
```